# Changing task owner in a GXFlow business process diagram

Tags: business-process-management, genexus

I'm working with GeneXus and I'm developing a business process diagram for GXFlow.
I need that the user can select the owner of the next task.
I can retrieve the list of the users of the specific role with this code:

```
&WorkflowServer.Connect('WFADMINISTRATOR','WFADMINISTRATOR')
&WorkflowOrganizationalModel = &WorkflowServer.GetOrganizationalModel()
&WorkflowFilter.Role = &WorkflowOrganizationalModel.GetRoleByName('RoleName')
&WorkflowUsers = &WorkflowOrganizationalModel.ListUsers(&WorkflowFilter) 

//Adding users to a combobox
For &WorkflowUser in &WorkflowUsers
        &users.AddItem( &WorkflowUser.Id.ToString(),&WorkflowUser.Name)     
EndFor
```

In this case a user can select the owner of the next task from a combobox. How I can set the selected user as owner of the next task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best solution for my question. I hope it can be useful also for you:

You can save the selected user in a relevant data variable.
In the target task properties you can change the property "Assign from a user in a relevant data" and assign the previous created variable to it.

This works good for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Is Ad-Hoc" property for a task and GXflow will do this automatically for you. Please see this documentation for more details about this option https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?11875,Is+Ad-Hoc+Property

Comment: I want that the user can only choose the user who assign the next task (limited by a list of users of the specific roles enabled for the task), I don't want that the user can choose what's the next task.

Comment: You can use WorkflowProcessInstance.PreassignWorkitem(activity, user)​ (see here https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?17771,WorkflowProcessInstance+Data+Type, ) or you can use the property Assign From a User in a Relevant Data (see here https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?11889,Assign+From+a+User+in+a+Relevant+Data+Property, )

Comment: Thanks Eugenio, this solution can be good but I found a better solution for my case by using "Assign from a user in a relevant data" task property.